# allowTextInput not working in office UI Fabric Datepicker

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I have created a date picker with Office-ui-fabric-react. I have enabled the "allowTextInput" property. I can able to edit the text input in Chrome, but its not working in IE 11.

Observed behavior:

Chrome: Working fine in both Keyboard Navigation and in Mouse click.
IE 11: Working fine in Keyboard Navigation, but cannot able to edit on mouse click.

Comment: This may be a bug with IE11. If so I suggest creating an issue at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/new/choose

Comment: Thanks kevin. I have already created an issue in office dev portal.

Comment: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/6008#issuecomment-419257396 ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was closed. Please find more details on the below link.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/6008#issuecomment-419257396

the solution on linked comment look like this:

```
<div aria-label=”Tag” role=”combobox” aria-expanded=”true” aria-owns=”owned_listbox” aria-haspopup=”listbox”>
  <input type=”text” aria-autocomplete=”list” aria-controls=”owned_listbox” aria-activedescendant=”selected_option”>
</div>
<ul role=”listbox” id=”owned_listbox”>
  <li role=”option”>Zebra</li>
  <li role=”option” id=”selected_option”>Zoom</li>
</ul>
```